# Moving data from many machines to a server using Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast

We have a goal of moving text-file represented database table row coming from several machines to a single machine, our current solution is file based
- Zip the files then send it over the wire
- Server will receive zip files from those machines and unzip to some folder according.

There are lots of other file moving operation in between that is happening which is really faulty.

I'm thinking of using hazlecast to move the each "row" String into the server. Is Hazelcast up to this kind of job?

The text file is being generate from many machines with a rate of 200K to 300K per day. These files must be send to the server. So I want to migrate this to Hazelcast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with hazelcast, but it is the wrong use case for it. Hazelcast will synchronize in all directions. If you add an entry on client1 it will be transfered to the server but also to client2. Even if this doesn't scare you it shows hazelcast is mis-used here.

You will be better by implement a simple webservice on the server to which the clients pushes the "rows".

Comment: I actually finished the application for the client, it works fine, but was not deployed.

Comment: Anyway, it was worth the shot. Doing web service is really painful for this kind of problem, that's why I used Hazelcast in a different way

Comment: For reason that, logs from servers gets "lost in translation" with this approach we are sure that logs are safe in the cluster